# Database log messages (auto cleaning) with keeping exceptions

Tags: log-messages

I can see that the Drupal has a settings about logs to keep, but when some amount is configured, so after X logs, the oldest are deleted.

Is there any option to make some logs not to be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **Database log messages to keep**, there is an **All** option to keep all logs.  However, there is no option to selectively delete logs automatically in core.

There are two things you could try instead:

First, the **Recent log messages** screen is a view.  So, if you have the Views UI module enabled, you can edit the log messages view to create a new view mode (for example, a separate page) and then customize the configuration on that page to only list the types of log messages you want to automatically delete.  You can then trigger this manually at whatever interval you want.

Another option would be to use the [Logging and Alerts](https://www.drupal.org/project/logging_alerts) module to store the logs you want to keep forever by copying them to email, SMS, or some other server.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanx for your reply. It is useful. I do have a View UI module, but I can't see any possibility to choose what kind of options of selectbox `Type` I want to keep or remove. Maybe it is not possible neither. And other thing, You mean, I can separate config of two Recent logs, where one of them can delete logs after X items, and another view config dont have to?

Comment: @maxo I can't explain how to use Views in a comment, but if you go to `/admin/structure/views/view/watchdog/edit/page`, you can edit what is displayed on the "Recent log messages" page.  One thing you can do from this screen is click the "Add" button under displays and add a new page, which you can customize to make a list of messages for deletion.  You will then have two recent messages logs, and you can customize the second to show the messages you want to delete.  You will have to do this manually, but it's very quick to set up.